# Select the entries that has at least one parameter different passing an array

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I've been developing a web application using zend framework 1.2, MySql and google maps to create some markers dynamically. For that I've have a table that has this structure:

```
id      lat       long     name
----------------------------------------------------
1       12.4       20.5    myHotSpot
```

So imagine that one special user can upload a csv with this structure to update the coordinates in this table. But before that, I would like check what are the entries that will be update in order to the user confirm this alteration.

For that reason I would like a query that passing an array return what are the entries that will be update.

I know that I could use a foreach or while, etc. and use a query in this way:

```
foreach($items as $item){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM markers where id = ? and 
((lat is null or lat != ?) or (long is null or long != ?))";

$result = $this->freqDb->fetchRow($sql, array($item->id, $item->lat, $item->long), Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
if($result)
    $element[] = $item;

}
```

But, i would like to know if there is another way only using a query.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM markers 
WHERE CONCAT( `id` , ',', `lat` , ',', `log` , ';' ) 
NOT IN ('csv_file_line1', 'csv_file_line2');
```

This way you will check all lines from your csv file in 1 query.

EDIT: there is one missing where clause there:

```
AND `id` IN (IDs from csv file)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but has one problem that is it will not match the ids os the markers

Comment: Yes, thats right. I have noticed that after a while. During the csv parsing process, you would have to create 2 arrays: one with just id's (that should be possible IF they are at the beginning of the csv file) and second array with whole csv lines...